# AWS instance doesn't start after reattaching root volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have a t1.micro instance with /dev/sda1 volume attached. Now I am out of disk space and migrating to a larger volume. I created the larger volume from the original disk snapshot and attached it to a new instance (for test) as /dev/sda1. The instance doesn't start with error:

```
Invalid value 'i-cf3acXXX' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/xvda)
```

If I attach the volume as /dev/xvda, the instance doesn't start. First, it goes into "Running" state, but then the state falls back to "Stopped".

There are threads on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137872/ec2-instance-doesnt-start-after-reattaching-the-volume) and [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=727740#727740), but they both seem to be obsolete and not helping.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried to create a new instance from this snapshot, instead of creating a volume from it?

Comment: Apparently, you can create only a volume, or an image from a snapshot... Volumes can then be attached to an instance.

Comment: Then try to attach it to a new instance. No guarantees, just see if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is actually what I am doing...

Comment: Create a new instance with a clean root volume, just like starting fresh. Then attach the old one. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, attaching it as a data volume works. Attaching it as the root volume doesn't work.

Comment: I've flagged your question to move it to https://serverfault.com/. I think there you'll find better support for this.

Answer (score 6):

Invalid value 'i-cf3acXXX' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/xvda)

your instance is pointing to root device name "[/dev/xvda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyF2b.png)". So the attached volume should also be mounted at same location but in your case it is mounted at /dev/sda1.

Hence while attaching the volume enter /dev/xvda against device text box.

[image]